# Redmine - partial rendering full page instead of part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a route

```
match 'time_loggers/render_menu', to: 'time_loggers#render_menu', via: %i[get post]
```

and function for this route

```
def render_menu
   @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
   @issue = Issue.find_by_id(params[:issue_id])
   render partial: 'time_loggers/embed_menu'
end
```

And there is my AJAX request for this route

```
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
function updateTimeLoggerMenu() {
$.ajax({
    url:"<%=url_for :controller => '/time_loggers',:action => 'render_menu' %>",
    data:({<%= (@project.nil? ? nil : "project_id:#{@project.id}") %><%= ((@issue.nil? or @issue.id.nil?) ? nil : ", issue_id:#{@issue.id}") %>}),
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#time-logger-menu').html(data);
    },
});
}
<% end %>
```

So that's work fine. But on one page, instead of rendering only part from `_embed_menu.html.erb` I (Only `<div>Test content</div>` inside it)

`console.log(data);` from other pages returns correct partial. `<div>Test content</div>`

specific page returns full rendering page.

So on the result I have next views:

[image]

Comment: Don't put the images of code in question, put the code itself instead.

Comment: Can't exactly see what's happening but are you doing a js request on the pages that work and an html request on the view that is returning the full page?

Comment: @BenTrewern as I said - I make a request for partial render function. On all pages (instead of my password recover page) it returns the only line <div>Test content</div>. On password recover page - it returns full html of the current page ( I'm console logging the data)

Comment: @BenTrewern I added the screen. On other pages displays only "test content". On this page - Full duplicate of current page, so I'ts kill my browser because recursive js call's

Comment: @BenTrewern Oh, I found the reason. Because of security reasons all requests from user who not changed the password redirects to the current page.

Comment: @BenTrewern yes, there is before_action :require_login

Comment: Great, got there.

Comment: @BenTrewern yep, it always redirects to request.original_url, that a root of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So there was `before_action :require_login` that redirect all my AJAX request back to the "Change password" page. Fixed by adding a condition that checks the current controller and action before AJAX part.